Trying to rename feature classes with loop
I keep getting a ERROR 000670: Output Output Data cannot be the same as input Input Data Element when trying to rename feature classes. I need to remove the 'Clip' suffix from all of them. Why exactly does it think my output is the same as the input?
nameList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
     for fc in nameList:
         split = fc.split('Clip')
         new_name = split[0]
         arcpy.Rename_management(fc, new_name, 'FeatureClass')
         print(new_name)


We don't know the content of namelist, so it's difficult to predict, but I'd guess there was a name without "Clip" in it.

if "Clip" in fc:
